# Android issue - Using handler while taking picture

Tags: android, timer, camera, handler, runnable

I am trying to show the total image taking time(timer) to the user in my android application.

**What I did:**

I am starting the Handler when the fragment starts. (i.e) I have started the handler in my "onCreateView" method as like below.

```
MainFragment:

private long startTime = 0L;
private long timeInMillies = 0L;
private long timeSwap = 0L;
private long finalTime = 0L;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.capture,
                container, false);
    TextView textview = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.timer);

    startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable updateTimer = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            timeInMillies = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
            finalTime = timeSwap + timeInMillies;
            int seconds = (int) (finalTime / 1000);
            seconds = seconds % 60;
            int milliseconds = (int) (finalTime % 1000);
            milliseconds = milliseconds % 60 ;
            textview.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds) + ":" + String.format("%02d", milliseconds) + "s");
            myHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }

    };
    myHandler.postDelayed(updateTimer, 0);

    .
    .
    .
    return rootView;
}
```

**What I want:**

The handler is running well and timer runs without delaying like(**00.00, 00.01, 00.02, 00.03, 00.04, ......, 10.32**) until I start to call the "**camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback);**". Once I call the "**camera.takePicture**" the timer shows the time with some sec delay(**00.00, 00.01, 00.02, 00.03, delay, 02.30, 02.31, 02.32, delay, 04.03, 04.04, ......**)

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    .
    .
    .
    camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback);
}
```

What would be the problem? Did anyone face this issue? How do I fix this issue?